# Tags not found in Wagtail Blog: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns

Tags: wagtail

I'm following the [Wagtail v2.4 tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/getting_started/tutorial.html) and added tagging functionality to the blog. However, when I click on the tag link on a blog post I get a 404 error. The Tags index page (`/tags/`) shows all posts that do not have any tags. I created only one post with a tag.

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/tags/tag%3Dnewswithimages
>
> Using the URLconf defined in koamrn.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. ^django-admin/
> 2. ^admin/
> 3. ^documents/
> 4. ^search/$ [name='search']
> 5. ^_util/authenticate_with_password/(\d+)/(\d+)/$[name='wagtailcore_authenticate_with_password']
> 6. ^_util/login/$ [name='wagtailcore_login']
> 7. ^((?:[\w-]+/)*)$ [name='wagtail_serve']
> 8. ^static/(?P.*)$
> 9. ^media/(?P.*)$
>
> The current path, tags/tag=newswithimages, didn't match any of these.

I'm guessing I need to add a path in `urls.py`?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    url(r'^pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Serve static and media files from development server
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`news_tag_index_page.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% if request.GET.tag|length %}
        <h4>Showing pages tagged "{{ request.GET.tag }}"</h4>
    {% endif %}

    {% for newspage in newspages %}

        <p>
            <strong><a href="{% pageurl newspage %}">{{ newspage.title }}</a></strong><br />
            <small>Revised: {{ newspage.latest_revision_created_at }}</small><br />
            {% if newspage.author %}
                <p>By {{ newspage.author.profile }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </p>

    {% empty %}
        No pages found with that tag.
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL to the tag listing page should be `/tags?tag=newswithimages`, not `tags/tag=newswithimages`. Most likely, you've made a typo in the link on `blog_page.html`:

```
<a href="{% slugurl 'tags' %}?tag={{ tag }}"><button type="button">{{ tag }}</button></a>
```

Comment: Yes! I was missing the question mark before `tag={{ tag }}`. Thanks @gasman!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to continue reading the tutorial :)

"Visiting a blog post with tags should now show a set of linked buttons at the bottom - one for each tag. However, clicking a button will get you a 404, since we haven’t yet defined a “tags” view."

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/getting_started/tutorial.html#tagging-posts